# How to remove NA from certain columns only using R

Tags: r

I got data which has many columns but I want to remove NAs values from specific columns
If i got a df such as below

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2), admission = c("2001/01/01", 
"2001/03/01", "NA", "2005/01/01"), discharged = c("2001/01/07", 
"NA", "NA", "2005/01/03")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

and I want to exclude the records for each id which has NAs in it and get the df such as below

```
structure(list(id2 = c(1, 2), admission2 = c("2001/01/01", "2005/01/01"
), discharged2 = c("2001/01/07", "2005/01/03")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `NA`s in the data are `"NA"`.  Convert to `NA` with `is.na` and then use `na.omit`

```
is.na(df1) <- df1 == "NA"
df1 <- na.omit(df1)
df1
  id  admission discharged
1  1 2001/01/01 2001/01/07
4  2 2005/01/01 2005/01/03
```

---

If it is specific columns, use

```
df1[complete.cases(df1[c("admission", "discharged")]),]
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the NA is present in a "Date" class column and there are NAs in other columns but I want remove NAs from the date column?

Comment: @kamrankhan Do you have `class` as `Date` or just character?  In the data you showed it is just character class.  I

Comment: @kamrankhan if you have `Date` class i.e. `df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], as.Date, format = '%Y/%m/%d')` then create an index `i1 <- sapply(df1, class) == "Date"` and use complete.cases on that `df1[complete.cases(df1[i1]),]`

Comment: Yes in the example data it is character but in my actual data it shows as "Date" and its not working.

Comment: @kamrankhan then the code I showed in the comments should work. Can you check `i1 <- sapply(df1, class) == "Date"` the value of 'i1'. Does it have any `TRUE` values?

Comment: @kamrankhan why can't the update works `df1[complete.cases(df1[c("admission", "discharged")]),]` here we are specifically subsetting the columns

Comment: I solved the issue by using nas <- with(df, which(is.na(admission) | is.na(discharged)))
df2 <- df[-nas,]

Comment: @kamrankhan i think the same should work with `complete.cases` though

Answer (score 1):

Base R option:

1. character `"NA"` to NA
2. then use `complete.cases`

```
df[df=="NA"] <- NA
dfNA <- complete.cases(df)
df[dfNA,]
```

```
  id  admission discharged
1  1 2001/01/01 2001/01/07
4  2 2005/01/01 2005/01/03
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make like this too:

```
library(tidyr)
df1[df1=="NA"] <- NA
df1_new <- df1 %>% drop_na()
df1_new
  id  admission discharged
1  1 2001/01/01 2001/01/07
2  2 2005/01/01 2005/01/03
```